# Class containing SKSpriteNode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a class, player, containing an SKSpriteNode.

In my GameScene, I have a world SKNode, which should be the parent for all players. As such, in the init function for the player, I pass in the world as an argument, and I have [world addChild:character], which character being the SKSpriteNode.

However, the node is seemingly never added to the world. This example works when moving all player-related functions, including the actual SKSpriteNode to GameScene.

Here's some sample code

GameScene.h

```
@interface GameScene : SKScene {
    SKNode * world;

    Player * player;
. . .
```

GameScene.m

```
@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    world = [SKNode node];
    [self addChild:world];
. . .
    [player init:world imageName:@"Spaceship"];
. . .
```

Player.h

```
@interface Player : NSObject {
    SKSpriteNode * character;
}

-(void) init: (SKNode *) parent imageName: (NSString *) name;
. . .
```

Player.m

```
-(void)init:(SKNode *)parent imageName:(NSString *)name {
    character = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:name];
    character.position = CGPointMake(128 * 5, 128 * 5);
    . . .

    [parent addChild:character];
}
. . .
```

Comment: `player` is `nil` so the `init` method is never called.

Comment: @0x141E I feel like an idiot. Objective-C is not my primary language, and it was like 2 AM, but that was still stupid. Thanks a lot!